# Get count from Objection.js query using withGraphJoined

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

I have a really simple query and I'm trying to get the count.

```js
const query = Product.query()
  .withGraphJoined('collections')
  .whereIn('collections.id', [1,3]);
```

I tried `resultSize()`, which worked on other queries I made that didn't use `withGraphJoined`. The only thing that works is if I do `count()` on the query, which returns the following:

```
Product {
  'count(*)': 6,
  id: 1,
  name: 'product',
  slug: 'slug',
  price: 32,
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do a total count on queries with `withGraphJoined`?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to count the collections associated with the Product? You can just do:

```
const query = Product.query()
  .whereIn('id', [1,3])
  .select([
     Product.ref('*'),
     Product.relatedQuery('collections').count().as('collectionsCount')
  ])
```